# UINavigationItem 'searchController' Bug(?)

Tags: ios11, xcode9-beta

I’m using the new UINavigationItem 'searchController' property and it’s working great except for one issue.

Here's a screen shot of my view controller with the search bar in use:

[image: search bar in use]

The problem occurs when I select an item and then push a view controller that does not display the navigation bar onto the navigation stack. Here's the result:

[image: bug with empty space where nav bar would be if displayed]

All of a sudden I have all this space at the top of the screen.

`'navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: true)'` does not do anything because the nav bar is already hidden on the previous screen.

```
'searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false'
```

will fix the weird space issue, but I don't want the nav bar displayed during a search:

[image: fix with issues]

What is the real solution for this? Is this in fact a bug? I think so, yes?

Comment: I'm having the same issue - when I tap into the search bar, it jumps down that space - can you post the code to your class?

Comment: How did you manage to configure the view controller to show the search bar in navigation bar as shown in the first screenshot? My search bar is shown below a navigation bar title even when I set the title to nil and do not have any right or left bar button items.

Comment: That first screenshot is of the search bar in use (once I tapped on the search bar). My default state has a title. Once the search bar is activated, the title will disappear unless 'searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false' is set. You can see what that looks like in the third image. Perhaps if you activate the search bar via code you can achieve the same result.